# Clang Tool (libtooling): set header search path to standard libs headers. Foundation framework

Tags: c++, compilation, include, header-files, llvm-clang

related link http://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling-example

I'am using `CommonOptionsParser` to parse arguments for clang tool:

```
// parse the command-line args passed to your code
CommonOptionsParser op(argc, argv);
// create a new Clang Tool instance (a LibTooling environment)
ClangTool Tool(op.getCompilations(), op.getSourcePathList());

// run the Clang Tool, creating a new FrontendAction (explained below)
int result = Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<SomeAction>());
```

and next parameters:

```
llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/mytool  /somePath/someSource.mm --
```

When I run my tool (based on clang libtooling) on some source file, tool tries find included files, f.e:
`#import “SomeClass.h”`, or `#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>`

And if it cannot find headers, it generates errors:

> fatal error: ‘Foundation/Foundation.h’ file not found.

Could you tell me, if you know, how can I direct tool to the standard frameworks? And How can I direct it to the some header search path? How can I set headers search path when running tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've solved the issue.
you can add path to framework with options

> -Iinclude -Ipath_for_foundation/Headers

after `--`

```
llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/mytool  /somePath/someSource.mm -- -Iinclude -Ipath_for_foundation/Headers
```

BUT, standard frameworks usually included with name of framework as prefixes

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

frameworks sources are placed in the folder called `Headers`, so clang cannot find them.
So, i'am going to find solution for that issue.

UPDATE:

solution

```
llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/mytool  /somePath/someSource.mm -- -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered your problem this Friday. One approach is to add your system header path directly by calling [AddPath()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FrontendAction.html#afa6f957361691a8c15a67e17a743f0a5) in function [BeginInvocation()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FrontendAction.html#afa6f957361691a8c15a67e17a743f0a5)
. A *HeaderSearchOptions* which includes *AddPath()* can be obtained from a *CompilerInstance* which can be obtained from a *FrontendAction*. With *LibTooling*, we can get an instance of FrontendAction.

References:

[clang::HeaderSearchOptions](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1HeaderSearchOptions.html#a18bc3848e478f8a45338dfaa5285f0af)

[clang::CompilerInstance](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CompilerInstance.html)

[clang::FrontendAction](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FrontendAction.html)