# How to provide header files when parsing C++ files using libtooling Clang API

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to build a source-to-source translation tool using Clang LibTooling based on [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html) tutorial. Here is the code that I'm using to pass the C++ source code file to be parsed as arguments to my program:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
  ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                 OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());
  return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<clang::SyntaxOnlyAction>().get());
}
```

and then I call it like this:
`bin/mytoolname file_to_parse.cpp --`

It can resolve all the standard library header files but cannot find the non-standard header files that are referenced using `#include`s. How can I provide it with a directory to search for the header files?

Comment: @xaxxon I'm not talking about libtooling. I'm just mentioning how to tell the compiler to find includes *in general*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that's not the question.

Comment: This question is about when calling into clang at runtime from an already-compiled program and asking clang to parse data your program is passing to it - how to tell it the equivalent of the -I flag when using clang as a traditional compiler.. but how to do that as an API call into the clang API.

Comment: Give this a shot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952307/clang-tool-libtooling-set-header-search-path-to-standard-libs-headers-founda

Comment: I think Jesper Juhl is right that it is easiest to do it with -I option and xaxxon is right that the OP may be wanted to ask how to supply those options to CommonOptionsParser or how to retrieve these from it or something. It is usually also fault of asker when understanding what was asked is ambiguous.

Comment: @Öö Tiib  it's not ambiguous at all.   It's just that if you don't understand that clang has an API then you don't understand what the question is asking.  There is no "-I" flag to a program that you build as is clearly laid out in the question (which is written quite well)

Comment: @xaxxon You're exactly right. What I wanted was the equivalent of the -I flag but when calling the Clang API in a program. I was able to get past the error by using the workaround you provided in the next comment (giving arguments to the compiler after --).