# How to redirect headers path?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, clang, libtool

I am parsing a large code using [libtooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html). However the code has alot of headers from OS
`#include <OSheader.h>` which leads to a lot of errors when parsing.
How can I automatically redirect the path of such headers into certain file /directory/of/OS headers ?
I know for sure the `-I` option when compiling but It does not work with such headers.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952307/clang-tool-libtooling-set-header-search-path-to-standard-libs-headers-founda

Comment: -- -F/path/to/System/headers option does not work :(